# Why can't I translate element using transform: translateY()?

Tags: html, css

I tried to move only the letter *'h'* down by 40px, but the translation only work if I move the entire word. I talso tried to put *'h'* in position absolute relative to the parent but *'ello'* loses it's original position.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="word">
    <span class="character first" style="transition-delay: 0s;">h</span>
    <span class="character" style="transition-delay: 0.025s;">e</span>
    <span class="character" style="transition-delay: 0.05s;">l</span>
    <span class="character" style="transition-delay: 0.075s;">l</span>
    <span class="character" style="transition-delay: 0.1s;">o</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

span {
  font-size:60px;
}

.word {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: coral;
  display: inline-block;
}

.first {
  transform: translateY(40px);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform doesn't work on inline elements.

```
.first {
  display:inline-block;
  transform: translateY(40px);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `span` element's CSS as given below:

```css
span {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Span cannot have transform property, to transform it you should add "display: block" to this element or just use div instead

```
.first {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    display: block;
}
```

OR

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="word">
    <div class="character first" style="transition-delay: 0s;">h</div>
    <div class="character" style="transition-delay: 0.025s;">e</div>
    <div class="character" style="transition-delay: 0.05s;">l</div>
    <div class="character" style="transition-delay: 0.075s;">l</div>
    <div class="character" style="transition-delay: 0.1s;">o</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not call the class correct

```css
#word-h {
   transform: translateY(40px);
}
```

```html
<span id="word-h" class="character first" style="transition-delay: 0s;">h</span>
```

Comment: After putting this into a snippet, this doesn't seems to work